# Storing invalid format of XML in active MQ

Tags: wso2, activemq-classic, wso2-esb

I am stuck on below,

I have set content type as XML in my proxy.
As below:

```
<parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
    <rules xmlns="">
        <jmsProperty>contentType</jmsProperty>
        <default>application/xml</default>
    </rules>
</parameter>
```

Sending below message into the queue which is correct one

```
<Data>
<name>abc</name>
<account>1212</account>
</Data>
```

But if any tag is missing in it as below. I dont want lose that message instead I want it to store in one special queue

```
<Data>
<name>abc
<account>1212</account>
```

Any guidance will be appreciated.Thanks